# Why is this parsing of JSON failing in django/python

Tags: python, django

The code below ends up printing failure.

```
    try:
        print request.raw_post_data
        json_data = simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
    except:
        print "failure"
```

The out put of the first print is

```
    JSON: {"password":"wfbarks","email":"wfbarks","username":"wfbarks"}
```

Does anybody know what is wrong this this?

Comment: You should avoid using "catch-all" excepts as they will make debugging a lot harder, or just raise the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just threw that in there to figure out where the problem was, for this case.

Comment: You could then use a raise statement in your except clause so you can get the traceback ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSON:` part is not valid JSON. Strip it before `loads`. The remainder (i.e. `{"password":"wfbarks","email":"wfbarks","username":"wfbarks"}`) should be valid JSON.